# How to search for elements of a given array in an array of objects and take some values from them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of field names and an array of objects which contain all properties of fields for a module.

Given the fields1, how can i search in fields2 and take some other properties for this fields using javascript(basically i want to output fields3)?

```
const fields1 = ['analysis', 'casecreator'];

const fields2 = [
        {
            name: "analysis",
            label: "Analysis8D",
            mandatory: false,           
            uitype: "10",          
        },
        {
            name: "automatic_close",
            label: "Automatic Close",
            mandatory: false,             
            uitype: "56",
        },
        {
            name: "casecreator",
            label: "Case Creator",
            mandatory: false,              
            uitype: "2",
        }
]

const fields3 = [
         {
            name:"Analysis8D",
            uitype: "10"
         },
         {
            name:"Case Creator",
            uitype: "2"
         }
     ]
```

Comment: are you trying to match what is in fields1 to the name value of what is in fields2, then grab the uitype and match it to something in fields3 ?

Comment: @MichaelCacciano, yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` like so:

```js
const fields1 = ["analysis", "casecreator"];
const fields2 = [{"name":"analysis","label":"Analysis8D","mandatory":false,"uitype":"10",},{"name":"automatic_close","label":"Automatic Close","mandatory":false,"uitype":"56",},{"name":"casecreator","label":"Case Creator","mandatory":false,"uitype":"2",}];

const res = fields2.reduce((a, { name, label, uitype }) => fields1.includes(name) ? a.concat({ name: label, uitype }) : a, []);

console.log(res);
```

Use `filter` and `map` for a more conventional, but less efficient approach:

```js
const fields1 = ["analysis", "casecreator"];
const fields2 = [{"name":"analysis","label":"Analysis8D","mandatory":false,"uitype":"10",},{"name":"automatic_close","label":"Automatic Close","mandatory":false,"uitype":"56",},{"name":"casecreator","label":"Case Creator","mandatory":false,"uitype":"2",}];

const res = fields2.filter(({ name }) => fields1.includes(name)).map(({ label: name, uitype }) => ({ name, uitype }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to filter the array `fields2` first by checking the present of `name` property in `fields1`, and then map to create your desired objects.

```js
const fields1 = ['analysis', 'casecreator'];

const fields2 = [{
    "name": "analysis",
    "label": "Analysis8D",
    "mandatory": false,
    "uitype": "10",
  },
  {
    "name": "automatic_close",
    "label": "Automatic Close",
    "mandatory": false,
    "uitype": "56",
  },
  {
    "name": "casecreator",
    "label": "Case Creator",
    "mandatory": false,
    "uitype": "2",
  }
]

const fields3 = fields2.filter(({
  name
}) => fields1.includes(name)).map(({
  label,
  uitype
}) => ({
  name: label,
  uitype
}))

console.log(fields3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its dirty but this is to make you understand the concept.

```
var fields3 = []

for (let i = 0; i < fields1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < fields2.length; j++) {
   if (fields1[i] == fields2[j].name) {
      var arry = { name: fields2[j].label, uitype: fields2[j].uitype }
      this.fields3.push(arry)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `forEach` loop like this:

```js
    const fields1= ["analysis", "casecreator"];
    
    const fields2= [
            {
                "name": "analysis",
                "label": "Analysis8D",
                "mandatory": false,           
                "uitype": "10",          
            },
            {
                "name": "automatic_close",
                "label": "Automatic Close",
                "mandatory": false,             
                "uitype": "56",
            },
            {
                "name": "casecreator",
                "label": "Case Creator",
                "mandatory": false,              
                "uitype": "2",
            }
    ]
    
    const fields3 = [];
    
    fields1.forEach((field) => {
      
      const selectedRow = fields2.find((row) => row.name === field);
    
      if (selectedRow) {
         fields3.push({
           name: selectedRow.name,
           uitype: selectedRow.uitype
         });
       }
    
    });
    
    console.log(fields3);
```

I hope it will help.